# i got the error message: Object not found and error 404, when i click Delete Button using PHP and codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

When I click the delete button, the javascript appear, but when I click 'ok', I got the error message.

Here's my code:

The controller file:

```
public function delete(){
            $this->mpbk_grup->delete($id);
            redirect('cpbk_grup/index');
        }
```

The model file:

```
   function delete($ID){
            $this->db->where("ID",  $id);
            $this->db->delete('pbk_groups');
        }
```

The view file:

```
<div class="box-body">
              <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>NO</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th width="104"></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <?php   $no=1;
                    $n=0;
                    foreach ($pbk_groups as $pbg) { $n++; ?>
                <tr>
                    <td width='10'><?php echo $no++; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $pbg->Name; ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo anchor('cpbk_grup/edit','<i class=fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> Edit', array('class'=>'btn btn-danger btn-sm"'))?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="javascript:if(confirm('and yakin ingin menghapus??')){document.location='<?php echo base_url();?>cpbk_grup/delete<?php echo $pbg->ID; ?>';}" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"> Delete</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>


              </table>
            </div>
```

Hope, you can help me, because I don't know what to do now!  :''(

Comment: Shouldn't here be a slash between delete and the ID in the href:  cpbk_grup/delete/<?php echo $pbg->ID; ?>

Comment: yeah, but it's doesn't work when i add the slash

Answer (score 1):

**1st :** `URL` value should be enclosed by `single quotes` or `double quotes`

```
<a href="javascript:if(confirm('and yakin ingin menghapus??')){ document.location="<?php echo base_url();?>cpbk_grup/delete/<?php echo $pbg->ID; ?>"; }" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"> Delete</a>
```

**2nd :** you missed `(/)` slash before the id

```
document.location="<?php echo base_url();?>cpbk_grup/delete/<?php echo $pbg->ID; ?>";
```

**3rd :** you need to get the `id` value from `uri parameter` like below

**Controller:** Don't forgot to load the `url helper` .

```
public function delete(){

        $id=$this->uri->segment(3);

        $this->mpbk_grup->delete($id);
        redirect('cpbk_grup/index');
    }
```

**Model :** your getting the value in model in `uppercase` but in query using `lowercase` `variables` are `case sensitive` take care about that

```
     function delete($ID){
            $this->db->where("ID",  $ID);
            $this->db->delete('pbk_groups');
        }
```

**`Load` the `modal`** in `autoload`

If you find that you need a particular model globally throughout your application, you can tell CodeIgniter to auto-load it during system initialization. This is done by opening the `application/config/autoload.php` file and adding the model to the autoload array.

```
$autoload['model'] = array('mpbk_grup');
```

Comment: same before :(((

Comment: show me the browser rendered value of  `document.location=`

Comment: above url is right one ? what is your controller name ?

Comment: just comment the modal calling line then give a try .it's redirecting to index page or not `public function delete(){
            //$this->mpbk_grup->delete($id);
            redirect('cpbk_grup/index');
        }`

Comment: yes, it's redirecting to same page with same url browser

Comment: I think your not loaded your modal in autoload ?  @TitiA

Comment: umm... i don't know.
then, what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Controller

```
public function delete($id){
            $this->mpbk_grup->delete($id);
            redirect('cpbk_grup/index');
        }
```

View

```
 <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/delete/<?php echo $pbg->ID; ?>"  onclick="return confirm('and yakin ingin menghapus??');"class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"> Delete</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting id on controller that you want to delete
get it from url like this on controller

```
$id=$this->uri->segment(4);
$this->mpbk_grup->delete($id);
redirect('cpbk_grup/index');
```